# How can I use a Mint Live DVD with separate persistent storage of customizations on a USB drive?

Tags: linux-mint, livecd

I am looking for a tool or "recipe" to set up persistent storage on a USB drive for a LiveDVD installation of Mint.

My situation is that I have a laptop that will not recognize a LiveUSB and boot directly from it, but will boot from its DVD drive.  I'd like to regularly use Mint on that machine, but the usage would be greatly enhanced with persistent storage.

I've hunted around this and other stack exchange sites and google and have found tools and recipes to set up a LiveUSB with its own persistent storage, or ways to modify the LiveDVD (modifying the boot process so that it points to persistent storage on another device, but have not found a method to just point the LiveDVD installation to another device for storage of customizations after booting.

I'm looking to have the LiveDVD entirely generic (so it can be replaced as new ISOs come out for updates), and keep the persistent storage separate.  I assume I would have to give a command line command after boot to make the running OS aware of the persistent storage.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure about that edit to the title.  The way I envisioned this, the O/S wouldn't be installed on the USB, it would just be used as persistent storage for customizations of the LiveDVD.  I don't think "chainload" describes what I'm looking for.  But maybe I don't understand the term.

Comment: Could you clarify if it would it be enough for your use case that certain directories (e.g. `/home`) would be mounted from the USB drive, or are you looking to emulate a writable root on the LiveDVD itself?

Comment: I am looking to emulate the "persistence" feature of some LiveCD installations (see, for example, http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/home).  I don't know how that is done, so I don't know how to answer your question.

Comment: Those can either be simply a disk image stored on the Live USB which is loop mounted in the live environment, or they can use an overlay, implemented as a [Device Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper) [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) snapshot, in which case each change (writes _and_ deletes) subtracts from its free space (this is typical for LiveUSBs with an persistent overlay), or some kind of overlay filesystem (such as UnionFS, Aufs or OverlayFS) in which case the backing storage might only be a (non-persistent) ramfs/tmpfs (typical for LiveCDs).

Comment: Please explain what kinds of data you want to store. Is this your own stuff, or do you want to install packages and have those available next time you boot? It might be a better idea to ask why you can't boot from USB (this could be fixable). Also, why don't you just install the system normally? If you will be using it regularly, it makes no sense to work on a live version.

Comment: To answer these questions: goal is storage of both customizations and data.  The reasons to run in this configuration is lack of control over the system - can't install O/S, can't address the problem of booting from USB.

Answer (score 1):

Use PLoP. You'll need a Window's machine to set up a cd. Instead of booting to the USB, you will boot to the cd which will then give you the option to boot from your USB. It's kinda a hack but it should work.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following guides:

[How to install Linux Mint via USB](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/744)

Or

[Linux Mint 13 Mate Live USB](http://www.computersnyou.com/210/2012/05/linux-mint-13-mate-live-usb/)

Of course, update of them is easy.

Comment: Not seeking to boot to USB or install on USB - this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work, and i'm too lazy to try it now. Create an ext2/3/4 partition on the USB flash drive, and label it *casper-rw*. If you want a separate home partition, make another partition named *home-rw*.

Most of the changes should work out of the box from one mint version to another, if an update break the system, you should run the former disk and run the release upgader or format the casper-rw partition.

comment: you can create those partitions on the disk instead of using a flash drive.